# Is there a way to lower your falsetto threshold?

Tags: voice, falsetto

When I go down the notes with falsetto, I reach a point where my voice cracks and I go into my normal chest voice.

My question is, is there a way to lower this 'threshold' before going into chest voice?

Comment: are you trying to avoid the cracking/smooth the chest voice-falsetto transition or trying to extend your low end 'falsetto' range? i would think more people would be familiar with trying to smooth chest-falsetto transition.  somewhat related is this [video from another answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDy2BgE-ddg) that mentions bridging this gap and [the cover](http://www.voiceteacher.com/male_voice.html)/darkening vowels.

Comment: I was moreso trying to extend the low end falsetto range. It currently lies at around the A above middle C, but I would like to get it down a bit lower.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably find you don't have a single threshold between falsetto and chest/head voices, but instead these ranges overlap. Many singers work on extending the range of their head voice upwards to have a more full-bodied sound in a higher register.

Low-pitched falsetto is a bit of an oxymoron, I'm not entirely sure what you hope to achieve, but you'll find there's a point where your voice loses that thin, squeaky sound. You could try to sing 'at a whisper' to have a thinner kind of sound at lower registers, it's really a question of what you want to achieve.

The obvious workaround, of course, is just to sing a little higher when you want a falsetto sound. Raise the key a few steps, or skip up an octave if you can.

Comment: One exercise my singing teacher has me doing is to sing a pitch and to vary its production as smoothly as I can between chest voice and head voice.

Comment: In one particular song, there is a line where the notes range from comfortably falsetto to comfortably chest. My aim is to either try to get it all within chest (difficult for me at the moment) or to get it all within falsetto, which is why I was wondering how to lower that threshold.

Comment: It may be better to just look at where in the phrase you can alter your vocal production. A common technique is to break into a higher register at a climactic point in a song. Perhaps use a little more of the warmth of your chest voice when changing vocal production and time it to emphasise an important word?